# Codeigniter remove index.php

Tags: codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter 2.1.1 my site structure is like

```
mysite/
    application/
        controllers/
            backend/
                welcome.php

            welcome.php

        views/
            backend/
            frontend/

        .htaccess
```

and I can access backend with

```
http://localhost/mysite/index.php/backend
```

but I want

```
http://localhost/mysite/backend
```

Similarly for frontend I want

```
http://localhost/mysite/
```

In config/config.php I set

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and experiment many code in .htaccess the latest one is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: do you have mod_rewrite enabled on your local server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.htaccess`should be in the root of your site, one level above the `application`folder.

Comment: I moved but when I write http://localhost/mysite/backend it showed me localhost main page

Comment: @PHPFerrari Did you move it into `/mysite/` ?

Comment: yes exactly one level above application eg:
mysite/
       .htaccess
        application/

Comment: Default it was AUTO I replaced with REQUEST_URI but nothing happened

Comment: Also see if removing the forward slash before `index.php` in your `.htaccess` makes any difference -  mine is very similar, but doesn't have the forward slash.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16487/discussion-between-php-ferrari-and-mudshark)